# enter a list into a class can't get object out

Tags: python, class

I have a class:

```
class Cycle:
    def __init__(self, datalist):
        self.data = datalist[::]
        self.n = len(self.data)
        self.pointer = 0
```

Then I import a list object:

```
months = Cycle(['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'])
```

But I can't get anything out:

```
'APR' in months
```

TypeError: argument of type 'Cycle' is not iterable

How can I make that work?  Sorry, just learning Python.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend your class with the special contains method:

```
class Cycle:
    def __init__(self, datalist):
        # initializer contents here

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self.data
```